# Can I insert a blank line after each file is processed with gnu `find`?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gnu

Using gnu `find`, I would like to separate the output generated for each file by an empty line. I tried adding `-printf '\n'`, but this was executed only once (oddly, after the first file's output, as I'd put it at the end of the command line).

Here's a sample of what I was trying:

```
find . -name eval_results.txt -print -exec cat {} \; -printf '\n'
```

Comment: i cannot reproduce your problem. Your sample code works as expected (i.e. output of each file is separated by empty lines).  tested in GNU bash version 4.4.23. An alternative is to replace `-printf '\n'` with `-exec echo \;` which produces the same output

Comment: One possibility is that the last line is not terminated in (some of) the files.  In that case the `-printf '\n'` will ensure that output for different files does not get combined on a single line, but it won't insert an empty line.  One possible fix is to use `grep ^` instead of `cat`.  `grep` appears to always terminate lines that it prints.

Comment: @pjh you're exactly right - it's files with and without final newlines. Tempted to delete the question, but maybe I'll leave it here in case someone else is confused by similar output. If you post an answer I'll accept it (:

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following once. I tried checking for `.csv` files you could change them as per your need too.

```
find -type f -iname "*.csv" -print -exec awk '1;END{print ""}' {} \;
```

Output will be as follows.(files output as per my system's file's content)

```
./file2.csv
timestamp, forecast, v1, v2 
2016-02-02 00:00:00, 68.56, 012, .23
2016-02-02 00:10:00, 23.24, .25, .32

./file1.csv
datetime, forecast
2016-02-02 00:00:00, 23.34
2016-02-02 00:10:00, 29.23

./file3.csv
timestamp, forecast[ma], v1
2016-02-02 00:00:00, 56.32, 32
2016-02-02 00:10:00, 25.21, 56
```

Though I tested your command too and it is working fine for me(you could take it as alternative and try it out once). Above command is tested on find's `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git` on Ubuntu system just as a fyi.

Comment: Nice solution! This produces exactly one empty line after each files contents irrespective of final newlines in the files.